# null pointer exception in android inListActivity in my custom adapter

Tags: android

I use ListActivity and i parse the json and placed it in my custom adapter to display it in ListActivity i.e,

```
DonorAdapter.java

package com.example.serverlogin;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class DonorAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Donor> {

ArrayList<Donor> donorList;
LayoutInflater vi;
int Resource;
ViewHolder holder;

public DonorAdapter (Context context , int resource ,ArrayList<Donor> objects)
{
    super(context, resource, objects);
    vi = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    Resource = resource;
    donorList = objects;

}
@Override
public View getView(int position ,View convertView,ViewGroup parent)
{
    View v = convertView;
    if(v==null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder.imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv1);
        holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        holder.phoneNo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        holder.remark =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        holder.id =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv4);
        holder.location=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv5);
        holder.officeLocation =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv6);
        holder.officePhone =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv7);
        holder.resPhone =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv8);
        holder.cellPhone=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv9);
        holder.email =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv10);
        holder.birthdate =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv11);
        holder.gender = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv12);
        holder.lastBloodDonation=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv13);
    }

    else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();

    }

    //holder.imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    holder.name.setText(donorList.get(position).getFname()+" "+donorList.get(position).getLname());
    String text ="";
    /*if( donorList.get(position).getRemark()== null)
        text ="";
    else
        text = donorList.get(position).getRemark();*/

    holder.remark.setText(donorList.get(position).getRemark());
    holder.id.setText(Integer.toString(donorList.get(position).getDonor_id()));
    holder.location.setText(donorList.get(position).getLocation());
    holder.officeLocation.setText(donorList.get(position).getOfficeLocation());
    holder.officePhone.setText(donorList.get(position).getOfficePhone());
    holder.resPhone.setText(donorList.get(position).getResPhone());
    holder.cellPhone.setText(donorList.get(position).getCellPhone());
    holder.email.setText(donorList.get(position).getEmail());
    holder.birthdate.setText(donorList.get(position).getBirthDate());
    holder.gender.setText(donorList.get(position).getGender());
    holder.lastBloodDonation.setText(donorList.get(position).getLastBlooddonation());

    return v;

}

static class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageview;
    public TextView name;
    public TextView phoneNo;
    public TextView remark;
    public TextView id;
    public TextView location;
    public TextView officeLocation;
    public TextView officePhone;

    public TextView resPhone;
    public TextView cellPhone;
    public TextView email;
    public TextView birthdate;
    public TextView gender;
    public TextView lastBloodDonation;


}


}
```

---

Donors.java

```
package com.example.serverlogin;

 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
 import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
  import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
  import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
 import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONObject;


  import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
   import android.net.NetworkInfo;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
  import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.ListActivity;
  import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Context;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.ListView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

public class Donors extends ListActivity {
Boolean success = false ;
String url="";

ArrayList <Donor>  donorsList = new ArrayList<Donor>();
DonorAdapter adapter;
int count =0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.donors);


     try{
            ConnectivityManager c =(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);                  
            NetworkInfo n =c.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (n!= null && n.isConnected()){

                url = "http://192.168.1.100/my/donors.json";

                new Background().execute(url);
            }
           }catch(Exception e){}

     adapter = new DonorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row,donorsList);

     setListAdapter(adapter);


}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    DisplayToast(donorsList.get(position).getFname());


}



class Background extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>
{
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    String check = "";
    int count=0;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Donors.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading, please wait");
        dialog.setTitle("Connecting server");
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);


        DisplayToast("Calling Background");

    }



    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(arg0[0]);
        HttpResponse response;
         Log.d("url",arg0[0]);
        try{

            response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

            if(response!=null)
            {
                /*if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()==200)
                {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    if (entity != null)
                    {
                        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                        check = convertStreamToString(instream);
                        if(check.equals(""))
                        {
                            check = "no data from file";
                        }


                    }

                }*/



                /*
                 Gson gson = new Gson();
                 JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
                 jsonReader.beginObject();

                 Log.d("gson","json");
                 while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
                      //get the element name
                      String name = jsonReader.nextName();
                      Log.d("gson2","json");
                      if (name.equals("success")) {
                       success = jsonReader.nextBoolean();
                      }
                      //if the element name is the list of countries then start the array
                      else if(name.equals("donors")){
                       jsonReader.beginArray();
                       while (jsonReader.hasNext()) {
                        //parse every element and convert that to a country object
                        Donor d = gson.fromJson(jsonReader, Donor.class);
                        Log.d("gson2",d.getAddress());
                        Log.d("gson2",d.getBirthDate());
                        Log.d("gson2",d.getBloodGrp());
                        Log.d("gson2",d.getCellPhone());
                        Log.d("gson2",d.getCity());
                        Log.d("gson2",d.getCountry());
                        Log.d("gson2",d.getEmail());
                        Log.d("gson2",d.getGender());
                        Log.d("gson2",d.getLastBlooddonation());






                        //add the country object to the list
                        donorsList.add(d);
                        count++;
                        Log.d("Inner count",Integer.toString(count));
                       }
                       Log.d("In count",Integer.toString(count));
                       jsonReader.endArray();
                      }
                     } 
                 jsonReader.endObject();
                 jsonReader.close(); 
                 */

                //My Logic

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);


                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("donors");
                String t ="";
                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Donor d = new Donor();
                    d.setDonor_id(object.getInt("donor_id"));
                    d.setFname(object.getString("fname"));
                    d.setMname(object.getString("mname"));
                    d.setLname(object.getString("lname"));
                    d.setAddress(object.getString("address"));
                    // edit req
                    d.setLocation(object.getString("location"));
                    d.setCountry(object.getString("country"));
                    d.setState(object.getString("state"));
                    d.setCity(object.getString("city"));
                    d.setOfficeLocation(object.getString("officeLocation"));
                    d.setOfficePincode(object.getInt("officePincode"));
                    d.setOfficePhone(object.getString("officePhone"));
                    d.setResPhone(object.getString("resPhone"));
                    d.setCellPhone(object.getString("cellPhone"));
                    //d.setEmail(object.getString("cellPhone"));


                    if(object.has("email"))
                    d.setEmail(object.getString("email"));


                    d.setBirthDate(object.getString("birthDate"));
                    d.setBloodGrp(object.getString("bloodGrp"));
                    d.setGender(object.getString("gender"));


                    if(object.has("remark"))
                    d.setRemark( object.getString("remark"));
                    d.setLastBlooddonation(object.getString("lastBlooddonation"));
                    donorsList.add(d);

                    Log.d("do in backgroung",Integer.toString(count++));
                }
                return true;



            }



        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("---////////////---", e.toString());
        }


        return false;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(Boolean result)
    {

        dialog.cancel();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(result == false)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to fetch data from server", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //DisplatToast(s);
        //btn1.setText(s);
    }


}


private void DisplayToast(String msg)
{
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}








}
```

and error at logcat is

```
 01-21 02:48:58.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1343): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 02:48:58.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1343): Process:     com.example.serverlogin, PID: 1343
01-21 02:48:58.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1343): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-21 02:48:58.553: E/AndroidRuntime(1343):     at      com.example.serverlogin.DonorAdapter.getView(DonorAdapter.java:62)
```

where is problem please some body help me.I am really thanks full to all. I am new in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(v==null)
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        v = vi.inflate(Resource, null);
        holder.imageview = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv1);
        holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        holder.phoneNo = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        holder.remark =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        holder.id =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv4);
        holder.location=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv5);
        holder.officeLocation =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv6);
        holder.officePhone =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv7);
        holder.resPhone =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv8);
        holder.cellPhone=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv9);
        holder.email =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv10);
        holder.birthdate =(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv11);
        holder.gender = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv12);
        holder.lastBloodDonation=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv13);

        v.setTag(holder); <==== add this line
    }
```